# Electron WebView Window Handle

Tags: javascript, electron

Does an Electron webview have a Window Handle similar to how a BrowserWindow does (IE BrowserWindow.getNativeWindowHandle)?

If so is it possible to retrieve the Window Handle of a webView?

My application needs to send an HWND to another application. The other application then uses the HWND to render data into. I can currently do this using a second child BrowserWindow but would prefer to embed it within the Main Window as opposed to a child window. Wondering if webview can provide what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should have a window handle for each webview in your electron application.

I'm using spectron, webdriverIO, and mocha/chai to test my electron application, here is how I am getting my windowHandles.

```
it('display window handles', function(){
    console.log("window handles:", await app.client.windowHandles());
})
```

this logs:

```
> window handles:  
>{    
>sessionId: '0926c9593e67dd7af2300d67b030db16',  
>status: 0,   
>value:   
>  [ 
>    'CDwindow-d195e5a4-21cf-413c-a2dc-be7fdb1e287f',
>    'CDwindow-11663947-f104-4ff1-906a-ca6f581dee9f'    
>  ]  
>}
```

value[1] is my webview. If you provide more details about your environment, we can help more.